# Conditional Probability (twice applied)

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

I am trying to better visualize why:
$$P(A|B,C) = [P(B|A,C)P(A|C)]/P(B|C)$$
I know we can get this by doing:
$$ \,\,\,(1)\, P(A|B,C) = P(A,B|C)/P(B|C) \\ (2)\,P(A,B|C) = P(B|A,C)P(A|C)$$

I can visualize the first equation via Venn Diagram. But I cannot visualize the second equation via Venn Diagram. Any advice on how to think about this problem, particularly the second? Any good (quick and visuals) resources?

Thanks.

Comment: What $P(A,B)$ means? $P(A\cap B)$?

Comment: How do you visualize conditional probability statements via Venn diagrams?